# How can i update android studio from 1.4 to 2.0?

Tags: android

I want to update android studio, I am facing problems can anyone suggest me the correct and easiest method?

my android studio version is 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can update android studio in two ways.
 1. Automatically -this can be done by just click on check for update if there is an update then click on update and restart.
 2. Manually - when you click on update it show a pop up window here you have to choose dev channel and then click on the download.
let me show you by steps
 3. After clicking download a webpage will open here select your
    platform    like window or another.
       2. After that a zip file will download.
       3. Extract that file.
       4. Go to c/program/android/androidstudio hide all the files in a folder. 5 Paste the data or files you got by extracting that
    downloaded folder here.  6 Now open your android studio , import all
    the setting and enjoy thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just simply delete the 1.4 from your computer and download the 2.0 from the link below
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

`AndroidStudio 1.4` can't update to `Android 2.0` automatically. You should download the new version manually by:

> Help -> Check for Update...

A dialog will appears, then you select Download
After that, it will navigate you to a website for download a new `AndroidStudio` version
When the download finish, extract the zip file, then run it
(after you run it you can import the settings that you use in `AndroidStudio 1.4` to `AndroidStudio 2.0`)

Anther solution is you can delete `AndroidStudio 1.4` from your computer then download the new `AndroidStudio version` (when you run it you will lose the setting in `AndroidStudio 1.4`)

Answer (score 0):

Download the new version as  [Dániel Hoffmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36835584/5521469) said.

Or follow the given steps.

1) Open Android Studio Help->Check for updates. [[see this]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO7Pb.png)

2) The prompt will come click "Update and Restart". (It may take few minutes to come that option so wait if it's not there.) [[see this]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTJlp.png)

Comment: your current `AndroidStudio is 1.5.1`  not `AndroidStudio 1.4`. when I try to update 1.4 to 2.0, there is no option "Update and Restart"

Comment: Just wait for serval minute it will come & if it's not coming then no option you have to download the new version.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you see from the pic,just click "Check Now" and you will know everything.